# Is it possible to get python pool results as they are completed?

Tags: python, multithreading

When using python multiprocessing pool is it possible to get the results as they are ready?

For example something like this where `results` yields a result when it is ready and not just when all results are ready.

```
args = [ ... ]
def foo():
    pass

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
results = pool.map_async(foo, l)

for result in results:
    save_result(result)
```

The only way I can think of doing this is

```
args = [ ... ]
results = []
def foo():
    pass

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

for arg in args:
    results.append(pool.apply_async(foo, arg))

while results:
    for result in results:
        if result.ready():
            save_result(result.get())
```

I am using Python 3.4 on Windows 7 x64

Comment: what version of python?

Comment: I am using Python 3.4 on Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using python 3.2+, far and away the easiest thing to do is use [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/concurrent.futures.html) instead of `multiprocessing.Pool`.  [`concurrent.futures.as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed) will give you an iterator that will yield results.. well, as completed.

Basic usage structure:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(foo, arg) for arg in some_args]
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        #do something with completed result
```

See the linked docs, it has some more examples to get you started.

Comment: I did not know about the `concurrent.futures` module. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Other responses have recommended concurrent.futures, but for certain applications, a process is not thread-safe and instead needs to be completed using multiprocessing.
For this application, I have found a way to do what you're asking.

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool_results = []
pool_results.append(pool.apply_async(<function>, (<args>)))
# ... add more function calls. possibly using loop ...

pool.close()
while len(pool_results) > 0:
    to_remove = [] #avoid removing objects during for_loop
    for r in pool_results:
        # check if process is finished
        if r.ready(): 
            # print result (or do any operation with result)
            print(r.get())
            to_remove.append(r)
    for remove in to_remove:
        pool_results.remove(remove)
    time.sleep(1) # ensures that this thread doesn't consume too much memory
pool.join() # make sure all processes are completed
```